# Wireless card for Virtualbox

Tags: wireless, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 host. Inside it I installed VirtualBox with Kali Linux. The Wireless for Kali is not working. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, inside the Virtual environment, there does not exist a "wireless" network or nic. There can only be wired ones as explained in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Network Card for Virtual Box in the Options, and set the Connection type to NAT, then reboot the VM for the settings to take effect.